# Mongo Groupby Aggregate Based on "Key" Not Value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, loopbackjs

I am stuck with mongo query. I have a mongo collection structure which i can not modify at this time as it is very large data.

I need to carry out some results from the collection , so tried all ways round to get it.

Here is my collection json schema:-

```
{
    "date": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bob":"P",
    "jacob":"P",
    "wilson":"A",
    "dev":"SL"
},
{
    "date": "2017-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bob":"P",
    "jacob":"A",
    "wilson":"A",
    "dev":"SL"
},
{
    "date": "2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "bob":"P",
    "jacob":"P",
    "wilson":"A",
    "dev":"SL"
},
{
    "date": "2017-01-04T00:00:00.000Z",
    "shashikant":"P",
    "jacob":"P",
    "wilson":"SL",
    "dev":"SL"
}
....
```

As output I am looking for below kind of structure:-

```
from 1st jan 2017 to 30th jan 2017

    bob      P      17
    bob      A      2
    wilson   P      10
    dev      SL.    1
    .....
```

I am using loopback for my backend but still i can use normal mongodb query to get the output.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allows $unwind only for the arrays. But you could use a simple [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) to achieve what you want:

```js
//Define the time frame here
var from = new Date('2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
var to = new Date('2025-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');

db.getCollection('test').mapReduce(function () {
  var keys = Object.keys(this);

  //If there is no date found on a record, simply skip
  if (!this.date) {
   return;
  }

  var date = new Date(this.date);

  //Skip the records that do not fit into [form; to] interval
  if (!(date >= from && date <= to)) {
   return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
   var key = keys[i];

   //Emit each combination of key and value
   if (key !== 'date' && key !== '_id') {
    emit({key: key, value: this[key]}, {count: 1});
   }
  }
 },

 function (key, values) {
  var reduced = {count: 0};

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
   var value = values[i];

   //Simply counting the combinations here
   reduced.count += value.count;
  }

  return reduced;
 },
 {
  //Passing the dates to mongo
  //so 'from' and 'to' will be avail in map, reduce and finalize
  scope: {from: from, to: to},
  finalize: function (key, reducedValue) {
   //Changing the data structure just for a convenience
   return {
    propertyName: key.key,
    propertyValue: key.value,
    from: from,
    to: to,
    count: reducedValue.count
   };
  },
  out: {inline: 1}
 }
);
```

I tested this in Mongo console, but map-reduces are also supported by mongo native Node.js and for mongoose as well.